# Hello, can anyone please help me understand and solve the problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity, distance

> ABCD is a track with a horizontal section BC of length 5 m. A 0.3 kg steel sphere is released from a point on the slope AB and it rolls towards the end D of the track. A stop watch was started shortly after the sphere passes B. The times at which the sphere passes various marks on the horizontal section are as follows:
>
> Distance from B in meters   2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
>
> Time in seconds             3.5  6.0  8.5  11.0

I'm stuck at understanding figuring out the time the stopwatch had started. From the given data set, it is clear that the sphere moved with a constant velocity along BC which is 0.4 m/s; so it travelled 0.4 meter every second. Considering that, the sphrere must have been at 1 Meter mark at 1s. I'm stuck as to how to figure out the starting time of the stopwatch.
Thank you!

Comment: The problem is unclear. You should add a diagram. This website is not meant to solve your homework: people will likely help you only if you explain your reasoning and your calculations until the point where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the differences between successive times, you can see that the sphere is taking $2.5$ seconds to cover each metre of track. It must therefore have passed point $B$ $5$ seconds before it reached the $2$ metre mark. I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: At t = 1 sec, it was at the 1 m mark.

Comment: gandalf61, thank you, I did figure out the time, just couldn't pull the logical explanations together, much appreciated.